# How to add custom DSL to Gremlin Console

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm using Gremlin console with AWS Neptune server.
I want to add custom DSL to shorten data analysis as described here: [DSL](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.1-SNAPSHOT/reference/#dsl)
So I can run queries as:

```
g.persons('marko').knows('josh').hasNext()
```

Instead of:

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').has('name','marko').out('knows').hasLabel('person').has('name','josh').hasNext()
```

If I understood correctly the documentation they describe how to extend the TinkerPop server, but since Neptune doesn't support that, I want to extend the Gremlin Console.
Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you absolutely need this in the Gremlin Console or will you eventually need to define a DSL using one of the Gremlin GLVs?

Comment: Since I'm starting with a POC, I thought starting quick and building it in the console. Later on if the project will progress I'll provide it as a library in some GLV. Any insights are welcomed. @Taylor Riggan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process for developing DSLs is the same for any case. Write your DSL as described in the documentation you referenced and then compile it to a jar file. Copy the jar file to the Gremlin Console `/lib` directory. Start the console and use the `import` command to reference your DSL classes so that you can use them.

From there you will need to connect to your graph using remote/bytecode-based traversals so assuming your DSL constructs a `SocialTraversalSource` as shown in the example you can:

```
gremlin> import com.mycompany.gremlin.dsl.SocialTraversalSource
...
gremlin> social = traversal(SocialTraversalSource.class).withRemote(...)
...
gremlin> social.persons("marko").knows("josh")
```

If you wanted to develop your DSL purely in the Gremlin Console then recall that you are just working in a Groovy environment and therefore have access to its full scope:

```
gremlin> g = traversal().withRemote('conf/remote-graph.properties')
==>graphtraversalsource[emptygraph[empty], standard]
gremlin> GraphTraversal.metaClass.knows = { String personName ->
......1>     return delegate.out("knows").hasLabel("person").has("name", personName)
......2> }
==>groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@6a638c79
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').knows('josh')
==>v[4]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').knows('josh').out().elementMap()
==>[id:5,label:software,name:ripple,lang:java]
==>[id:3,label:software,name:lop,lang:java]
```

With a bit of [metaprogramming](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html) you can hack in a DSL method without too much trouble.